# Conditionally include JS file without document.write

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I would like to add the async attribute to my javascript included files, BUT only if the useragent matches a specific string.

I cannot do this server side, because the page "might" be cached on the server side, so I need to detect the useragent with javascript and async it accordingly.

Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
<script id="myscript" type="text/javascript">
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/development/i)){
    document.write("<script type='text\/javascript' src='\/\/localhost\/static\/js\/header.min.js' async><\/script>\n");
} else { 
    document.write("<script type='text\/javascript' src='\/\/localhost\/static\/js\/header.min.js'><\/script>\n");
}
</script>
```

What I would like to achieve now, is to **replace the document.write** with something else, possibly just add the async attribute if the useragent match my string and make it load async for that useragent.

I also thought about reversing it, so by default I would load the tag with async and remove it if the useragent doesn't match my string (but the other way would be preferable).

This also doesn't seem to actually load the file asynchronously?

```
<script id="myscript" src="//localhost/static/js/header.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/development/i)){
    document.getElementById("myscript").setAttribute("async", "async");
}
</script>
```

I also need the script to stay render blocking to the other useragents, AND to add this in the exact place where the script appears in the html.
I believe this won't work either:

```
var scriptEle = document.createElement("script");
scriptEle.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
scriptEle.setAttribute("src","//localhost/static/js/header.min.js");
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/development/i)){
scriptEle.setAttribute("async","async");
}
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendElement(scriptEle);
```

I'm not so skilled with javascript, so if someone has a better idea... thanks.

Comment: Adding the "async" attribute afterwards is indeed useless, because the script is loaded synchronously, _then_ you reach the line that tells it to load asynchronously :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only other option you have here is to use document.createElement('script'), then give it a src attribute, then append it to the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to set the `src` attribute after setting (or not) the async :

```
<script id="myscript" src=""></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var myScript = document.getElementById("myscript");

   if(navigator.userAgent.match(/development/i)){
       myScript.setAttribute("async", "async");
   }
   myScript.setAttribute("src", "/static/js/header.min.js");
</script>
```

Comment: This looks like it could work (will try), but when I set the src attribute this way, will it still be render blocking? I mean, what if after this code, I have an inline script that depends on some other variables defined in that external file?

Comment: Well that's the very problem of loading a script asynchronously. You never know when it's loaded, so if another script depends on it, it will likely break.

Comment: I'll accept this, as it's working for what I need now. Thank you very much.